# How to make an image of splashscreen fit all mobile screen sizes?

Tags: android, splash-screen, gravity

The image I used for my splash screen with (**gravity:center**) doesn't fit my mobile screen, even if I changed gravity to fill.

```
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:src="@drawable/drawable"/>
</item>
```

Comment: Best not to use a bitmap to stretch the entire screen. Maybe you have some logo you can centre and the background colour you can set with xml

Answer (score 1):

Normally I used common single image for all kind of devices, which size is **720px*1280px**. 
Then in my `splash_activity.xml` i usually used it like following way:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_splash"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use the bitmap in the XML file as a background

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_splash"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **FrameLayout** as your Root
 Put an **ImageView** in it and set [ScaleType](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide) to `fitXY` and set [adjustViewBounds](https://proandroiddev.com/a-guide-for-android-imageview-scaletype-and-adjustviewbounds-64a1e4a35503) to `true`

**So change your layout like below:**

```
 <FramLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_splash"
 />
     </FrameLayout>
```